# Java Time API converting ISO 8601 to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java-time

I am having a hard time converting an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted String to a [java.time.LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) which is in UTC.

More specific, I am trying to write an [XMLAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) for which you can enter the various ISO 8601 dataformats as a String (i.e. `2002-09-24`, `2011-03-22T13:30`, `2015-05-24T12:25:15Z`, `2015-07-28T11:11:15.321+05:30`) and which outputs a LocalDateTime in UTC and visa versa.

The system stores all it's Date and Time information internal in UTC times. When a user requests a Date or Time it is represented to the user based on their own [ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Basils answer below should be marked correct. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083698/348956

As the name suggests `LocalDateTime` holds both Date and Time. The first example of a date string you have in your question for example only holds information about the date, therefore you cannot parse this directly into a `LocalDateTime`. What you could do there is to first parse it into a `LocalDate` and by setting the time on that object get a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDate.parse("2002-09-24").atStartOfDay();
```

All Date and Time objects have a parse method like `LocalDate` which can take a certain string format. These formats are different ISO standard formats specified in [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

For formatting custom datetime strings into `Temporal` objects use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and specify a custom pattern.

Comment: This answer is less than optimal. `LocalDateTime` purposely lacks any info about time zone or offset-from-UTC. There is no need to ignore or dispose of that vital info in this situation. Also, you are implicitly applying the JVM’s current default time zone with your call to `atStartOfDay`. So results will vary by whatever the current default time zone may be.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2015-05-24T12:25:15Z" )
       .atZone( 
           ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
       )
       .toString()
```

> 2015-05-24T08:25:15-04:00[America/Montreal]

## `ZonedDateTime` vs `LocalDateTime`

Your Question contradicts itself, with the title asking for a `ZonedDateTime` and the body asking for a `LocalDateTime`. Those are two very different beasts. One (`ZonedDateTime`) is a specific moment on the timeline, the other (`LocalDateTime`) is only a vague idea about *possible* moments but is **not** a specific moment.

For example, the `LocalDateTime` of Christmas starting this year is `2017-12-25T00:00:00` but that has no meaning until you apply a time zone as Santa delivers first to the islands of [Kiribati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiribati) at their midnight (the first midnight on Earth), then on to New Zealand at their later midnight, then on to Australia at their later midnight, and so on moving westward toward successive midnights.

Also, you Question seems confused about exactly what is the input and what is the output.

> a java.time.LocalDateTime which is in UTC.

This is a contradiction in terms. The [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class lacks any concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So this class cannot be used to represent a moment such as a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) value. For a moment in UTC, use either [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) or [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) classes.

## `Instant`

For an input like `2015-05-24T12:25:15Z`, that represents a moment on the timeline in UTC (`Z` is short for `Zulu` and means UTC). To represent that, use the `Instant` class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2015-05-24T12:25:15Z" );
```

Generally you should be working in UTC for most business logic, data storage, data exchange, and database. So for that `Instant` is all you need.

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you need to adjust into a time zone, such as for presentation to a user, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

## `LocalDate`

If you have a date-only value, parse as a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2002-09-24" );
```

To get the first moment of the day for that date, specify a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the world by zone.

Also, do not assume the day starts at the time of `00:00:00`. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) may cause the first moment to be something like `01:00:00`. Let java.time determine the first moment’s time-of-day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( z );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are various formatters defined on [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)  which do the job.

**For example:**

```
TemporalAccessor accessor= DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse("2020-07-14T21:56:00Z");
ZonedDateTime from = ZonedDateTime.from(accessor);
```

**OR with a different offset format still in iso 8601 spec:**

```
TemporalAccessor accessor= DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse("2020-07-14T21:56:00+00:00");
ZonedDateTime from = ZonedDateTime.from(accessor);
```

**Note:** This only works for the 'extended' iso 8601 formats. I didn't find support for the simplified one (without -'s for example 20200714T215600Z) but I don't think that's a big deal. I just wont support the simplified format in my API. If anyone does find a way to support the iso 8601 simplified date format (not just the extended) that is not a lot of work and is happy to leave a solution that would be great :)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    private static final Pattern ZONE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("T.*(\\+|\\-|Z)");

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String isoDateTime) throws Exception {
        LocalDateTime utcDateTime;
        if (ZONE_PATTERN.matcher(isoDateTime).matches()) {
            OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(isoDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
            ZoneOffset offset = offsetDateTime.getOffset();
            utcDateTime = offsetDateTime.toLocalDateTime().plusSeconds(offset.getTotalSeconds());
        } else {
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(isoDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
            ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault(); // TODO: Get ZoneId from userProfile
            ZoneOffset offset = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId).getOffset();
            utcDateTime = localDateTime.minusSeconds(offset.getTotalSeconds());
        }
        return utcDateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDateTime utcDateTime) throws Exception {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault(); // TODO: Get ZoneId from userProfile
        ZoneOffset offset = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId).getOffset();
        return utcDateTime.plusSeconds(offset.getTotalSeconds()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
    }

}
```